# Missing Authorization header in Basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, basic-authentication

I used following code to implement Basic Authentication filter in my ASP.Net MVC app. everything is working good in local machine while it's not working in production server and it keeps prompting login box because `Request.Headers["Authorization"]` is null.
I used fiddler to get headers for this request and `Authorization` header was there with expected values. I have no idea why `Request.Headers["Authorization"]` is always null :|
I also created a new project only with this filter and one controller and published in server, guess what !? it's working...

```
public class RequireBasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string BasicRealm { get; set; }
    protected string Username { get; set; }
    protected string Password { get; set; }

    public RequireBasicAuthenticationAttribute()
    {
        this.Username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProtectedUsername"];
        this.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProtectedPassword"];
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
        auth.LogText();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
        {
            var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
            if (Username.Equals(user.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && Password.Equals(user.Pass)) return;
        }
        var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        res.StatusCode = 401;
        res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", BasicRealm ?? "bimeh-takmili"));
        res.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the client is definitely receiving the 401 status. There's this "thing" that i cant remember off the top of my head whereby if certain clients don't get a 401 they wont send the Auth header.

Comment: yeah, client gets 401 status code. I've doubt about mixing form and basic authentication enabled in IIS and I definitely need form authentication

Comment: Ok well I am surprised. And the last response is a 401.. You don't get a 401 and then a Server 500 error thus potentially undoing the 401 signal to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code I don't see how it runs at all, production or otherwise.

I would suggest it's throwing an error that your code is swallowing since the code below closes the response and then tries to call the base method.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        // this is really the key to bringing up the basic authentication login prompt.
        // this header is what tells the client we need basic authentication
        var res = context.HttpContext.Response;
        res.StatusCode = 401;
        res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        res.End();
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
```

You cant do this, the code will throw an error:

> Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

And since it's throwing an error (i think) and being bounced around, it might not be output a 401 status response. The "WWW-Authenticate" header is still being sent however which is why your getting a dialog.

The credentials dialog is popped a when "WWW-Authenticate" is detected but it will only send back an `Authorization` header in the request if it received a 401 status from the last response.

So if you drop:

```
base.ExecuteResult(context);
```

from your code, what happens?

**Edit:**

Actually dropping

```
res.End();
```

would be the way to go. Duh.